# Randomly downsample rows of a dataframe 1.Conserving the distribution of column labels OR 2.Same number of samples per each label?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataset that is very large and in the ' Label' column, it has 3 different class labels namely 'benign', 'webdos' and 'udp-lag'. I want to reduce the dataset by randomly selecting the data from the dataset while keeping the distribution of the class labels to an equal or similar number.

how can I effectively do it using python or any other equivalent python libraries?

[Link to the small dataset](https://drive.google.com/file/d/127UcPKIUT5EP_sBq8MrLmFALvq5KF14t/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: added link to the dataset

Comment: Thank you for adding dataframe. It would have been great if you could remove irrelevant columns as there are many in there. The more minimal reproducible example, the better. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Pandas has a built in function to sample data. You only need to give the frequency of class/labels as weights:

```
df['counts'] = df['target'].map(df['target'].value_counts())
df_downsample = df.sample(frac=0.4, weights='counts', axis=0)
```

You can either use argument `frac` to decide what fraction of original data frame to sample (here, for e.g. it returns 40% of original dataframe rows), or instead, **REPLACE** it with argument `n` for number of rows you desire in your down sampled dataframe (e.g. `df_downsample = df.sample(n=10, weights='counts', axis=0)`)

*EDIT*: per OP's comment, if you need a fixed number of instances `n` per **each** class, you can use groupby:

```
df_downsample  = df.groupby('target', group_keys=False).apply(lambda df: df.sample(n))
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. However, I am not getting the answer as I desire. I want the same number of class labels to be selected in an equal number when I randomly select from the big dataset. From your answer, I get the following result.  DrDoS_DNS:   2029; BENIGN: 2; Name:  Label, dtype: int64. What I want is 'BENIGN' to have a similar (2000) value to selected as of 'DrDoS_DNS' value of 2029.

Comment: So you do not want to have same distribution of classes but you want a fixed number of instances in each class? for e.g. 2000 of class benign and 2000 of class udp-lag and 2000 of class webdos? Please clarify and if that is the case, I will edit the answer accordingly.

Comment: @SomeshGupta Please see if the EDIT in the post resolves your issue. Thank you